# Changing how IKImageBrowserView indicates the drop position

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, imagekit

I can make a single row IKImageBrowserView by setting the

```
[imageBrowser setContentResizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
```

but in this case while i drag an image inside image browser to rearrange it, the drop place highlights with horizontal line(vertical line expected).

how can this be changed?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just curious how you attacked this.   I'm looking to resolve a similar issue.

Comment: just created my own image browser. ) cooler than the image kit one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no defined way to do what you want.

You may be better off writing your own custom view where you can control every detail of how things are drawn. In general, Apple's controls are "as-is" and unless they provide an explicit way to control behavior or mention that you can custom an object in some way, don't count on being able to do it easily (if at all).

I would also suggest heading to http://bugreport.apple.com and making the enhancement request - it would be best if you attached a sample application demonstrating the behavior.

EDIT: You could also try out the NSCollectionView to see if it might work for you.